# How to zoom gradually in leaflet, javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use leaflet and geojson-vt too displaing map, and some lines in vector tiles. I made some modifications in geojson-vt because i need to add some my functions when tiles are slicing. 
Everything works fine, when i start my leafletMap from zoom 1, and then increasing zoom by mouse wheel, to for example zoom=15. But There is a problem when i start my Map with zoom= for example 7,

```
var leafletMap = L.map('map').setView([52.00, 19.64], 7);
```

because the vector tiles are not beeing calcuated from 0 to 7, but only at 7, so "my function" dont working well.

I think that the solution will be to start map on zoom 0, and then in loop increasing zoom to 7. But i dont know how.

I tried this but it isn't working with multiple zooms...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    leafletMap.setZoom(2);       
}, 300);
...
setTimeout(function() {
    leafletMap.setZoom(7);       
}, 300);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you changed in geojson-vt or at least your custom functions and the code that calls them? I'm not sure that simply animating the zoom will cause your functions to execute and so may not draw the correct vector layers at each zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how to zoom in gradually. Part of the problem with your code is that you called sequential `setTimeout` methods with the same delay and so they will be executed one right after another. If you change the milliseconds so that they increase (`300`, `600`, `900`, ...) then you will actually see the animated zoom.

This was quick example using OSM tiles and not geojson-vt, so it looks a little clunky until your browser caches the tiles. However, with geojson-vt you are creating your own local vector tiles and so it should be a bit smoother.

However, I'm not sure this will solve your problem because you didn't show the code you changed in geojson-vt. It may be that `setZoom()` isn't triggering your functions, but until you show those custom functions it will be hard to get a proper answer to your question.

```js
var zoomDelayMs = 600; // milliseconds for animation delay
var maxZoom = 18;
var initialZoom = 7;

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -0.5], initialZoom);

// Set up the OSM layer
var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: maxZoom
  }).addTo(map);

// function to zoom in gradually from initialZoom to maxZoom
slowZoom = function() {
  // reset zoom to default
  var zoom = initialZoom;
  map.setZoom(zoom);

  // if already in middle of slow zoom, stop it
  if (map.zoomtimer) clearInterval(map.zoomtimer);

  // zoom in one level every zoomDelayMs
  map.zoomtimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (zoom < maxZoom)
      map.setZoom(++zoom);
    else {
      clearInterval(map.zoomtimer);
      map.zoomtimer = 0;
    }
  }, zoomDelayMs);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
input {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<input type='button' onclick='slowZoom()' value='Start slow zoom' />
<div id="map"></div>
```